# sqlserver hibernate date mapping

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate

I have a SQLServer and am using hibernate to map an entity to a table that I already have.
the table has a field of type "timestamp" `[field_date] timestamp NOT NULL` which is the only date the table has.

I have tried mapping it on an entity like this:

```
@Column(name="field_date")
private Date date;
```

and even

```
@Column(name="field_date",columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP")
private Date date;
```

but every time I try to do a select on that entity I get an SQLServerException of type

```
 Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from timestamp to TIMESTAMP is unsupported.
```

Comment: Whenever I use dates, I always use the @Temporal annotation to define what type it is. That hasn't failed me yet, but I have never used SQLServer so I don't feel comfortable providing it as an answer.

Comment: @Gimby yes, indeed @ Temporal, as peter suggested as well, proved to be the best solution in this case as well.Thank you nonetheless

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Try mapping it to the Java class java.sql.Timestamp.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html

Also here I would try removing this from your annotation
columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP"

2) Here is another mapping to try.
So alternatively you can try this approach.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "CreatedOn", nullable = false)
public Date getCreatedOn() {
    return this.createdOn;
}

public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
    this.createdOn = createdOn;
}
```

3) This is like 2) but it is to be used if you want 
mapping for the class field (not for the getter).

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "Last_Updated_Date", nullable=false)
private Date lastUpdatedDate;
```

Comment: Hello peter and thank you, your first suggestion did not work and gave the same exception, the @temporal annotation tough worked.Thank you